# Find all matches between two strings with Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

How to scan for all string between `*|` and `|*` in text like

```
Today is *|date|*. Weather is *|weather_description|*.
```

using Ruby `"string...".scan(...)`.

I would like to get array of matches: `["date", "weather_description"]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"Today is *|date|*. Weather is *|weather_description|*.".scan(/\*\|(.*?)\|\*/).flatten
# => ["date", "weather_description"]
```

Comment: You've made great progress over the past few months!